# JavaScript function that returns result of ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

Help needed. Im writing a function that returns result of ajax call but i did not get any results, i guess it's a scope issue, but is there any way to do it? Here is my code:

```
function Favorites() {
    var links;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Services/Favorite.svc/Favorites",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(msg) {
            links = (typeof msg.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + msg.d + ')') : msg.d;
        }
    });
    return links;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the HTTP request you're making is asnychronous and your `Favorites` function returns before the Ajax request has come back. You will need to change your function so that it accepts a callback to be executed once the response has come back:

```
function Favorites(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Services/Favorite.svc/Favorites",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(msg) {
            var links = (typeof msg.d == 'string') ? eval('(' + msg.d + ')') : msg.d;
            callback(links);
        }
    });
};

Favorites( function(links) { alert(links); } );
```

Aside: convention is that only functions intended to be used as constructors should start with a capital letter, so your function would be better named as `favorites`.

Answer (score 6):

Ajax is asynchronous, i.e. when `return links` is executed, the callback function in `success` might not even have been called.

Extend your function to accept a callback:

```
function Favorites(callback) {
    var links;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Services/Favorite.svc/Favorites",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: callback
    });
};
```

and call it with:

```
var callback = function(msg) {
      links = (typeof msg.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + msg.d + ')') : msg.d;
      // do other stuff with links here
}

Favorites(callback);
```