# vimeo-api. access 'duration' property outside the function

Tags: javascript, vimeo-api

I want to use the 'duration' of a video as a variable elsewhere in my javascripts (especially on event 'ready'), but I seem to be unable to access this property.

```
player.addEvent('ready', function() {
    ... 
    var duration='';
    player.api('getDuration', duration);

    function duration(data){
      $('somediv').text(data); //works fine
      duration = data;
    }
console.log(duration);     // doesn't work
```

What would be the right way to access this value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript function that returns result of ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682274/javascript-function-that-returns-result-of-ajax-call)

Comment: I think you are correct, CBroe. I have been able to get things working by moving all functionality into the same function. (I guess it is the nature of async that it is simply impossible to use such variables outside the scope.)